# Microsoft Word - adding page number to page not Header or Footer

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, page-numbers

I reformat texts to be readable by our students who read with Braille. We are always looking for ways to speed up our processes so that we can deliver more texts and deliver on time.

Part of this processing is to put the page number at the top of each page in the body and not in the Header or Footer as these are not accessible to the Braille user. The texts could be chapters of a book. Manually entering the page number is time-consuming as a manual process.

Each page is separated by a manual page break. I can replace all `^m` with `^m[page x]^p`, but I cannot find a way to get the x entered. Ideally would like a prompt to ask for a starting number and would like the start of each page to have the page number in format `[page 33]`. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer provide what you need? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. If not, please let us know what you more you need by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

### You can put page numbers in the ordinary text of a document with the Page field.

Simplest method **Shift+Alt+P** keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+P on the Mac).

You can also simply type the word "page," select it and press first Ctrl+F9 to make it a field and then F9 to update it.

Here is [my writing on Page Numbers in Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers) and on the [various pagination fields](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Pagination).

Unlike fields in the headers or footers, though, these do not update automatically when pagination changes. Pressing Print Preview should update them, even if you do not print.

If you need the page number to be in a particular place on the page, you can create a Frame with the Page field in it. Then save that frame as a Building Block/AutoText entry and use it to place your page number on each page. Frames can have a designated location, even in the margins, but are still part of the regular document story.

- Here is my writing on [Frames and TextBoxes](https://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#CreatingFrames)
- Here is my writing on [AutoText and Building Blocks](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm)